# How to get the number of keys in a php object

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have an arrays object whith one key user, and i try to get the size of this key, the sizeOf function return 6. But if i have more than one key user in my object then sizeOf return the number of key user.

Here is an exemple of my object :

```
object(Context)[347]
protected 'values' => 
array (size=23)
  [...]
  'user' => 
    array (size=6)
      'nom' => 
        array (size=2)
          '@content' => string 'foo' (length=6)
          '@attributes' => 

      'email' => string 'foon@yahoo.fr' (length=24)
  [...]
```

What the best way to get the number of user key in my object ?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

With multiple users i got this

```
object(Context)[347]
protected 'values' => 
array (size=23)
  [...]
  'user' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        array (size=6)
          'nom' => 
            array (size=2)
              '@content' => string 'foo' (length=6)
          'email' => string 'foo@yahoo.fr' (length=24)
      1 => 
        array (size=6)
          'nom' => 
            array (size=2)
              '@content' => string 'bar' (length=6)
          'email' => string 'bar@yahoo.fr' (length=24)
```

Comment: [array_keys](http://php.net/array_keys)

Answer (score 3):

Try with -

```
echo count(array_keys((array)$yourObject));
```

For multiple users -

```
$count = 0;
foreach((array)$yourObject as $value) {
    $count++;
}
echo $count;
```

Comment: if i got only one user key, then the count return 6

Comment: if you have more `users` then count inside a `foreach`.

Comment: should i test it like this :

`var_dump(array_keys((array) $context,'user'));`

Comment: Well, i did test it. It returns an empty array. It seems like it can't navigate into my `context` object...

Comment: Add an example with multiple users.

Answer (score 1):

There's no function to count the elements in an object.

There's a hack:
You can **cast** the object as an Array:

```
$arr = (array)$obj;
$count = count($arr);
```

You can also use the following if you're using a STD Class Object:

```
$arr = get_object_vars($some_std_class_object);
$count = count($arr);
```

I didn't understand what you the OP means by "number of user key", but once you get the Array, you can easily retrieve the count of any element in this Array.